# How can I fix a 2104 error in a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have an existing Silverlight application that's been running for a few months with lots of users. This week we had a new user try to use the application but he keeps getting this error message.

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Timestamp: Wed, 24 Nov 2010 03:49:04 UTC

Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2104
Category: InitializeError
Message: 2104 An error has occurred.

We're running IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2, the user has Silverlight 4 (4.0.50826.0) installed.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error maybe due to MIME types. You will have to add the following MIME types:

- .xaml   application/xaml+xml
- .xap    application/x-silverlight-app
- .xbap   application/x-ms-xbap

Comment: MIME types are configured. We've had many users using the app for some time now. If it were MIME types everyone would be getting the same error.